# how to hide dataformwebpart view ribbon tab

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

i am new to sharepoint, currently i am develop my site with sharepoint 2010 foundation, when i create a dataformwebpart and set the page to my homepage, an extra ribbon is coming out, my question is simple, how to disable the view ribbon?

[image: my website]

as you can see, there are view tab beside browse, how to disable it? thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to hide any Ribbon Tab is using JQuery, to do this you need just the tab id.

For example

```
$("#Ribbon\\.WikiPageTab-title").hide();
```

You can achieve your goal without any new deployment; just add a new content editor web part that contains this javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

       // in this example the target tab id is Ribbon.WikiPageTab-title but we 
       // must add \\ before the . to escape the selector character
       $("#Ribbon\\.WikiPageTab-title").hide();
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Result

[image]

PS :
You can find the tab Id by using the Internet Explorer "F12 Developer Tools"